# picasso image not loading in custom infoWindow why?

Tags: android, google-maps, picasso, infowindow

I'm trying to layout a custom infoWindow programmatically.  I want to load a streetView preview image using Picasso but the image isn't showing up, any idea why?

```
private View prepareInfoView(Marker marker){
    //prepare InfoView programmatically
    LinearLayout infoView = new LinearLayout(EarthquakeActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams infoViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    infoView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    // attach the above layout to the infoView
    infoView.setLayoutParams(infoViewParams);

    //create street view preview @ top
    ImageView streetViewPreviewIV = new ImageView(EarthquakeActivity.this);
    // this scales the image to match parents WIDTH?, but retain image's height??
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams streetViewImageViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    streetViewPreviewIV.setLayoutParams(streetViewImageViewParams);

    String imageURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=200x200&location=";
    String markerLongitude = Double.toString(marker.getPosition().longitude);
    String markerLatitude = Double.toString(marker.getPosition().latitude);
    imageURL += markerLatitude + "," + markerLongitude + "&fov=120&heading=0&pitch=0";
    Log.wtf("prepareInfoView", imageURL);

    Picasso.with(this).load(imageURL).into(streetViewPreviewIV);
    infoView.addView(streetViewPreviewIV);
```

I've tried with and without the api key appending the url.

It did work for a few clicks without the key, but hasn't since, with or without.  Is the because it's too slow fetching it so Android gives up and loads the info window without it?  Is there a best in class way to do this?

Would another image loading library work better?  Google's volley?

Also with

> LinearLayout.LayoutParams

I'd like the image to stretch across the width of the info windows, i.e. match_parent, and to scale vertically to maintain original aspect ratio, how do I do this?

This is my answer

In commonsWare new class I add this flag:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess() {
    Log.i(TAG, "image got, should rebuild window");
    if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "conditions met, redrawing window");
        marker.setTag(new Boolean("True"));
        marker.showInfoWindow();
    }
}
```

And in prepareInfoView, I test for the flags absence.

```
    if (marker.getTag() == null ) {
        Log.i("prepareInfoView", "fetching image");
        Picasso.with(this).load(imageURL).fetch(new MarkerCallback(marker));
    }
    else {
        Log.wtf("prepareInfoView", "building info window");
```

Party on! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is the because it's too slow fetching it so Android gives up and loads the info window without it?

Picasso loads asynchronously unless the image is cached. And the way Maps V2 works is that the `View` you return is converted into a `Bitmap`, and that is what gets rendered. As a result, you have a race condition between Picasso and Maps V2 (does the image get loaded before the `Bitmap` gets created?), and so it is indeterminate as to whether or not any given info window will work.

You can call `showInfoWindow()` on the `Marker` after Picasso has loaded the image, so you can populate the `ImageView` from Picasso's cache. `showInfoWindow()`, called on a `Marker`, triggers Maps V2 to regenerate the info window.

For example, you could change your existing `into()` call into `into(streetViewPreviewIV, new MarkerCallback(marker))`, with a `MarkerCallback` like:

```
  static class MarkerCallback implements Callback {
    Marker marker=null;

    MarkerCallback(Marker marker) {
      this.marker=marker;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
      Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error loading thumbnail!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
      if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
        marker.showInfoWindow();
      }
    }
  }
```

> Would another image loading library work better? Google's volley?

They will all suffer from the same issue.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, very instructive.  I like your solution, and implemented it but it triggers an infinite loop!  It keeps on fetching the image over and over.  Too tired to think this one out now, so thanks for your attention :)

Comment: @TonyStark: Ah, yeah, there's probably some bits in my overall adapter that avoid this. Here is the entire sample project: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/ImagePopups

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, I actually got your original code working, just used marker.setTag, to transfer a Boolean flag across. I'll update the question with the answer, and credit you.  One day I want to be commonsWare masterful :)

Comment: If this isn't working for you, make sure you're not using `.fit()`, `centerCrop` or other similar functions with Picasso. I'm trying to figure out how to resolve now.

Answer (score 7):

What is working for me is this:

```
public class MarkerCallback implements Callback {
    Marker marker=null;
    String URL;
    ImageView userPhoto;


    MarkerCallback(Marker marker, String URL, ImageView userPhoto) {
        this.marker=marker;
        this.URL = URL;
        this.userPhoto = userPhoto;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        //Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error loading thumbnail!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            marker.hideInfoWindow();

            Picasso.with(getActivity())
                    .load(URL)                        
                    .into(userPhoto);

            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this kinda' works. Leads to the info window flashing :(

Answer (score 4):

All I figured out is,
Picasso loads image asynchronously, so when a marker shows it's info window after clicking by internally calling the method **getInfoContents** or **getInfoWindow** method ,
by this time if the image isn't already downloaded or cached by Picasso , then it is not showed on infoWindow.
Picasso tries to load the image into imageview of **infoWindow** when downloaded, but According to Google maps V2, the **infoWindows** Once loaded, can't be manipulated, so image is not shown updated on the UI.
But the infowindow view was updated actually but couldn't show for the restriction, so if you just hide and show the **infowindow** , it is kind of refreshed, and the images are shown on updated **infoWindow**. you can do this in the following way,

You need to keep the marker reference, you can keep this as Activity/Fragment's member variable.

```
 Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(marker.getSnippet())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
                        .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                            if (currentClickedMarker != null && currentClickedMarker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
//toggle the marker's infoWindow
                                currentClickedMarker.hideInfoWindow();

                                currentClickedMarker.showInfoWindow();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well, here is a solution with glide inspired from the accepted answer.
This solution did not work for me without resizing the picture to a proper size. With `override()` (and `centerCrop`) it did the trick.

Keep track of the latest picture shown

```
private String previousImageUrl = null;
```

And use it to see if you need refreshing of the current image

```
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(final Marker marker) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_map_info_window, null);
        MyObject myObject = (MyObject) marker.getTag();
        final String url = myObject.getImageUrl();
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        GlideApp.with(getContext()).load(url)
                .override(imageWidth, imageHeight) // made the difference
                .centerCrop()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                        imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                        if (!TextUtils.equals(url, previousImageUrl)) {
                            previousImageUrl = url;
                            marker.showInfoWindow();
                        }
                    }
                });
        return view;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the accepted answer to fix the problem and it still doesn't work, 
you're probably using **.fit()** .
in other words you should remove **.fit()** from your Picasso code.
It took me a couple hours to realize it.