# CardView's corner radius acts strangely in Google Maps InfoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps, cardview

It looks like that the same XML layout code works differently in InfoWindow and "normal" activity/fragment.

I'm customizing my Google Maps InfoWindow. I've already applied rounded corners to it (I use `getInfoWindow()`) and now I'd like to make the ImageView have also rounded corners. When InfoWindow opens up, it shows like this
[image: Broken InfoWindow]
It looked strange to me, so I pasted the CardView and ImageView code (aftermentioned) to an activity. This is how it looked like (don't look at the content, it's loaded at runtime)
[image: Fine InfoWindow]

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_bg">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:cardCornerRadius="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:contentPadding="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageInfoWindow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/opactwo_2" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView <!-- Doesn't matter -->

    <TextView <!-- Doesn't matter -->

    <TextView <!-- Doesn't matter -->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I found out that the same code produces different result. My question is why it doesn't work and what should I do to make it work? I don't apply any theming nor modify views at runtime.

Comment: I don't know the full answer to your question, but a piece of information that could help you solve it is that Google Maps InfoWindows are **not** normal "live" android views, they are bitmaps! It's possible that whatever process converts the view to a bitmap is interacting strangely with CardView.

Comment: See the blue note section inside https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows#custom_info_windows for more info.

Comment: I am aware of that @BenP. I've been using Picasso but encountered this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551774/picasso-image-not-loading-in-custom-infowindow-why. So decided to load programatically by imageView.setImageResource(), this is an equivalent to hardcoding app:srcCompat

Comment: My point is that the rounded corner clipping behavior of CardView is not a very common thing in the platform (and doesn't even work at all pre-Lollipop), so perhaps the process that converts the view to a bitmap is happening "before" the CardView can perform its corner clipping.

Comment: My min is API 21 so I don't take care of that. But your version seems pretty good. I'm sure there must be some kind of a workaround

Answer (score 0):

so, I put https://github.com/rishabh876/RoundedImageView this instead of imageView and use Glide for image downloading

```
                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        if (!isFromMemoryCache) {
                            marker.showInfoWindow();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(viewHolder.imageView);
```